# How to list all language-related SE sites?

Tags: discussion, search, languages

I want to advertise StackExchange at a language-learning-related web, so it would be handy to provide a link to all language sites here. Or to all language-related ones, at best, but list of languages you can ask about would be enough. The categories used here are broader, so [the closest category search I already found](https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation) shows a lot of clutter. Search for word "language" should be better, but I didn't find any custom search at the site list (perhaps it's possible programatically, I don't know). I already tried to search for "language" at Area51, but even though I had "beta" tab active, proposals at all stages (mostly "definition") were shown.

Can I list the language sites some other way, or do I have to provide all the links one at a time, or let the people try to find the needle (language sites) in the haystack (all sites)?

Comment: Just thought of something from a different direction: [list of all questions across the network tagged grammar](http://stackexchange.com/filters/165432/all-language-sites), which 99% of the times mean language related.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to list the existing language sites, use your browser's search function to search for the word “Language” on the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites). You may or may not want to add [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

If you want a page listing the existing language sites were people can pick the one(s) they're interested it, I think you'll have to provide your own. If the audience is learners, omit English Language & Usage and Linguistics. If the audience also includes teachers, leave them in. In addition, you may want to list language proposals on Area 51, but take care that this is a moving target, and there too there isn't  reliable search (“language” should include them all but adds some noise with programming languages, sites about some other topic in a non-English language, etc.)