# {Request} Russian SE site for English language questions

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal, non-english-speakers

English SE site for Russian language questions exists.

Why no Russian SE site for English language questions? For example, it would be extremely useful to describe differences between synonyms or synonymic phrases. More of all - for people who begin to learn English (asking and explaining in English is difficult for them).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site)

Comment: @honk No, I propose here already.

Comment: That is not how things work @oleedd

Comment: Why don't the English Language Learners and Russian Language sites take care of the requirements here? I don't understand why this is required.

Answer (score 7):

> asking and explaining in English is difficult for them

Exactly, that's why they should *practice* English. [Immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_immersion) is very important when acquiring a language. On [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), we see almost exclusively questions by users whose first language is not English. As long as they try to be clear, our regulars can figure out what they mean.

> For example, it would be extremely useful to describe differences between synonyms or synonymic phrases.

It regularly happens that a question is asked like "In my native language, we have [word x] and [word y] which English seems to translate with a single [word z]. Can I really use it in this situation (where we always use [word x]) and in that situation (where we always use [word y])." One often does not need to be familiar with that language to explain how English handles it.

> English SE site for Russian language questions exists.

Yes. (Though it's actually bilingual; some questions are actually asked in Russian.) I guess Stack Exchange makes an exception for English, since English is the standard language of the network. All staff members speak English, so they can intervene if things get out of hand on an English site; AFAIK there's only one who speaks Russian.

Comment: English SE site for Russian exist. I think it is fair to create the opposite site.

Comment: About synonyms - it is often reversed. 1 word in Russian - 3-4 in English.

Comment: Glorfindel means that you can ask questions on the english site. Sites in a different language then English will not be created, see the answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: ">Exchange makes an exception for English" - Do you mean that only English has the reversed version?

Comment: @oleedd да. Russian having its own site dedicated to the Russian language ([rus.se]) is already a big exception (due to the site being taken over as part of the network that composed [ru.so]).

Comment: How to see the list of all language (only) SE sites?

Comment: @oleedd [How to list all language-related SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247246/295232)

Comment: I thought that another way exists (direct list) but OK +1. So few such sites((( Even no need to search.